# Index in foreach starts not with 0

Tags: foreach, key

```
    $rounds = $season->championsLeague->rounds->where('stage', 'Olympic')->take(2);
    $indexes = [];
    foreach ($rounds as $index => $round) {
        $indexes[] = $index;
    }

    echo '<pre>';print_r($indexes);echo '<pre>';
```

And I receive in indexes:      Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => 7
    )

How it is possible?
 Why not    Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
    )

Answer (score 0):

*The slice, chunk, and reverse methods now preserve keys on the collection. If you do not want these methods to preserve keys, use the values method on the Collection instance.* This is from laravel documentation. I think it is true for take method also.